# Bootstrap and formvalidation.io: display .help-block on one line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation-plugin

I use Bootstrap 3.3.4 and formvalidation 0.6.1 me need display .help-block for right to display errors formvalidation.io (i use .form-horizontal).

I tried to use (out of service):

```
.help-block {
    display: inline;
}
```

My form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action=""   id="formProfile">   

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">E-mail</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input name="email" id="email" 
type="email" class="form-control"
>
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nick" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nick</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input name="nick" id="nick" 
type="text" class="form-control"
>
</div></div>

</form>
```

**How to make what errors are displayed on the right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormValidation's [err.container](http://formvalidation.io/settings#form-err-container) option allows to define messages area in various options:
* A CSS selector
* A callback
* tooltip
* popover

In your case, you can use a callback to indicate the message area.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <!-- The messages are shown here -->
    <div class="col-sm-5 messageContainer"></div>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nick" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nick</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input name="nick" id="nick" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <!-- The messages are shown here -->
    <div class="col-sm-5 messageContainer"></div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#formProfile').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    err: {
        container: function($field, validator) {
            // Look at the markup
            //  <div class="col-sm-4">
            //      <field>
            //  </div>
            //  <div class="col-sm-5 messageContainer"></div>
            return $field.parent().next('.messageContainer');
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

The result looks like the following image:

[image: Showing messages in the right]

The [Showing messages in custom area](http://formvalidation.io/examples/showing-message-custom-area/) example also provides more helpful examples.

Answer (score 0):

put the *help-inline* block after div which contain input, and before *div.form-group* end.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nick" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nick</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input name="nick" id="nick" type="text" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <span class="help-block">This is Errors</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i not guessed. And how to do it through formvalidation.io?

Comment: sorry, i never used formvalidation before.

Comment: Maybe I gashel method ..`.help-block {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 100%;
 top: 5px;
}`